# MYSQL como consultar em 2 tabelas onde a consulta pode ou não existir em uma das tabelas?

Tags: mysql, mysqli

Boas pessoal!! Sou novo por aqui, preciso da ajuda de vocês.

Preciso criar uma tabela/consulta onde retorna os registros efetuados pelo usuário.
Este usuário pode ou não fazer parte de um grupo de trabalho, onde diversos usuários compartilham seus registros.

a) Preciso que os registros feitos pelo usuário sejam listados mesmo ele não ter vinculado nenhum grupo de trabalho;

b) Além disso, preciso que os registros desse usuário que foram vinculados à algum grupo de trabalho seja listado na mesma tabela/consulta;

c) E, caso haja registros de outros usuários que pertencem ao mesmo grupo de tralho seja listado.

Ex.:

Produto  |  User  |  Grupo  |  Empresa

Caixa1   |  1     |  22     |  589 
Caixa2   |  3     |  22     |  589 
Caixa3   |  1     |  NULL   |  589

*No exemplo os 3 resultados são verdadeiros.*

Tabelas:

1. **bemtbgeral** = tb1;
2. **gruposusercentral** = tb2;

A **tb1** é minha tabela principal, nela preciso verificar se o usuário tem acesso ao registro que ele mesmo criou (caduser), depois preciso trazer também os registros de outros usuários pertencentes ao mesmo grupo de trabalho (idgrupo). A **tb2** estão as informações de cada grupo de trabalho e usuário.

Meu código:

```
// caduser -> é a coluna com a id do usuário
// idesc -> é a coluna com a id da empresa do usuário
// idgrupo -> é a coluna com a id do grupo de trabalho que o usuário faz parte

"SELECT * FROM bemtbgeral AS tb1
WHERE tb1.caduser = '".$_SESSION['iduser']."'
OR EXISTS(SELECT * FROM gruposusercentral AS tb2
WHERE tb2.caduser = '".$_SESSION['iduser']."'
AND tb2.idesc = '".$_SESSION['idempresa']."'
AND tb2.idgrupo = tb1.idgrupo)";
```

Nessa consulta ele me retorna a primeira condição verdadeira, porém preciso que me traga as duas condições caso exista, tanto se existirem registro que ele mesmo criou quanto registros de outros membros do mesmo grupo.

Comment: Importante você [edit] sua pergunta e explicar de maneira objetiva e pontual a dificuldade encontrada, acompanhada de um [mcve] do problema e tentativa de solução. Para aproveitar melhor o site, entender e evitar fechamentos e negativações vale a pena ler o [Guia de sobrevivência do Stack Overflow em Português](https://pt.meta.stackoverflow.com/q/8045/70).

Comment: Não entendi o motivo de ter fechado minha pergunta... Já editei e acrescentei mais detalhes.

Comment: Tem uns links que eu passei no comentário anterior que explicam. Caso ainda assim realmente não tenha entendido como editar para reconsideração, pode tratar do assunto no [meta] com a tag "pergunta-específica" (e lilnk para a postagem)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Se entendi corretamente utilize uma junção.

```
SELECT * FROM bemtbgeral AS tb1 LEFT OUTER JOIN gruposusercentral AS tb2 ON (tb2.idgrupo = tb1.idgrupo)
WHERE tb1.caduser = '".$_SESSION['iduser']."'
OR tb2.caduser = '".$_SESSION['iduser']."'
AND tb2.idesc = '".$_SESSION['idempresa']."'
```

Comment: Agradeço pela ajuda. Estou testando a solução indicada, a princípio os registros que não possuem a "idgrupo" estão retornando como deveria, porém os registros que possuem a "idgrupo" retorna apenas o ultimo registro, replicando este ultimo registro pela quantidade total de resultados encontrados.

Comment: Deu certo amigo, acrescentei apenas "GROUP BY tb1.id". Muito obrigado pela grande ajuda!